# Save user database connection in my database

Tags: mysql, node.js, security, authentication, typeorm

I am developing an application where I have to create a connection to my own database, and a connection to the database with the access information that the user must provide in his own registration.

We are working on a unique application that should serve multiple customers, using node w/ typeORM on backend.

I know that for my connection I can use the .env from my own application.

But the connection that the user provides, I understand that I cannot save using plain text in the database.

So the question is: is it okay to save this to a mysql database?

How can I save this data in the most secure way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is a system design with some unusual information security hazards. It has a larger-than-usual [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface), because it requires your customers to expose their MySQL servers to connections from your servers.  If your server can get in, it's likely that cybercreeps will have an easier time getting in too. If their data is sensitive, they may require you to access their servers with an always-up VPN tunnel between their environment and yours.  How to do that? Beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

You can take some measures to make this safer.

First of all, get your customers to require [ssl-encrypted MySQL connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html) from your nodejs  program to your customer-furnished MySQL instances. You don't want your customers' data moving over the public network without encryption, because you don't want cybercreeps to intercept or alter it.  This requires your customers to configure their servers to support TLS.

Second, tell your customers to create MySQL accounts on their servers specifically for your application to use. Those accounts should have the minimum privileges they need  for your app to work.  Ask your customers to restrict access for those accounts to your server. For example, if your server's IP addresses are `192.0.2.123`, `192.0.2.124`, and `192.0.2.125` you can ask them to [create accounts like this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html):

```
 CREATE USER 'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.123' IDENTIFIED BY 'hardToGuess' REQUIRE SSL;
 CREATE USER 'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.124' IDENTIFIED BY 'hardToGuess' REQUIRE SSL;
 CREATE USER 'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.125' IDENTIFIED BY 'hardToGuess' REQUIRE SSL;
 GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON rodrigoAppDb.* TO
    'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.123',
    'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.124',
    'rodrigo'@'192.0.2.125';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Third, let's take advantage of a fact about password authentication to your application. If you're doing password authentication correctly, the only time you have access to *your* users' login passwords unhashed is when they POST them to you from your login form and [you check them](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-check-a-password).  Because you hash your users' passwords they aren't stored in your MySQL database in a usable form.

That means you can encrypt your customers' MySQL passwords using their login passwords (their **plain text login passwords themselves, not the hashes** of their login passwords) to your system as the their keys. That way you don't have to store the text of those passwords. You'll need to retrieve and decrypt their MySQL passwords during your login sequence. Then you can open a connection pool to each user's MySQL database for use during that user's session. (Be sure to set a short expiration time on each of those pools, so it goes away soon after your user goes away.)

Notice this:  w**hen your users change their passwords**, you will have to update both their password hash and re-encrypt their database passwords. That means you must prompt for a user's existing password and the new password on the password-update page.

Similarly you'll need a screen where you accept each user's MySQL connection data. On that screen you'll also have to re-request your user's password to your system.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.
I have one more question about password encryption using the user's password hash.
If the user changes his password, or for some other reason his password hash changes, will it be possible to continue decrypting mysql access data using the new hash?
Or would he have to re-encrypt his database access data?

Comment: Please see my additions to my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will talk with my team about this solution, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It's never a great idea to save the user's critical information in plain text. You could encrypt the data using the some kind of user related key and a salt for your organization and then save that information in database. Do not save the password and ask for that when user logs in so that this data cannot be misused at your end.